# how to add a new column without opening a csv file

Tags: python, excel, vba, csv

I scrapped data and exported as csv files.
For simplicity, the data look like below
(I intentionally put arbitrary variables to just illustrate an example):

```
id var1 var2 var3 ...
A  10   14    355 ...
B  35   56    22  ...
C  95   22    222 ...
D  44   55    222 ...
```

Since I collected the data daily, I saved my file name as city_20180814_result.csv
For example, if I collected the data in NYC at Aug 14th 2018, the corresponding file name is NYC_20180814_result.csv

Here, I want to add a new column, the date variable, into each csv file.
The desired example is going to be like the one below. To be specific, I want to add a date (YYYYMMDD as a format) column to each csv file and the values are going to be the date when the data were collected. For example, the below example csv file was generated on Aug 14th 2018, then the updated data will look like below:

```
id   date     var1 var2  var3 ...
A    20180814 10   14    355 ...
B    20180814 35   56    22  ...
C    20180814 95   22    222 ...
D    20180814 44   55    222 ...
```

The conventional way to do this is to open every csv file and manually add a new column, assign a corresponding date to all the rows, and repeat this step for all csv files. But there are too many to get this done. Is there any way to do this efficiently? Since I saved file names including the date, it would be a good idea to use this if it's possible. Any help/codes (by using python again or excel macro) would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you define 'efficient'? Do you want a short programme that uses least human effort, or you want the total processing time as short as possible?

Comment: There’s no way to modify a file without opening it. How could that even work?

Comment: @Kevin.Fang Hi Kevin, both way would be fine. I guess less human effort also would save some time or either way!

Comment: Well sometimes it takes more effort to optimise a programme. So by 'without opening it' do you mean literally 'open the file in Excel'? As @abarnert said you actually cannot modify a file without 'open' it in a programme.

Comment: @Kevin.Fang Yes. I meant 'without opening' by literally 'opening the file in excel'. If I could import the files on python and run codes that work, then it would be great.

Comment: Just in case you don’t know, excel can loop through files then open, change, and close them without your input. No need to involve python

Comment: [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), [research must be done to ask a good question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch). Why is this even tagged with `excel-vba`? OP clearly states he doesn't want to open it in excel.

Answer (score 1):

My solution using python's `pandas` package:

```
import os
import re
import pandas as pd

FILE_PATTERN = re.compile(r'(.*)_(\d{8})_result.csv')

def addDate(file_dir):
    csv_list = [csvfile for csvfile in os.listdir(file_dir) if re.fullmatch(FILE_PATTERN, csvfile)]
    for csvname in csv_list:
        date = re.fullmatch(FILE_PATTERN, csvname).group(2)
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(file_dir, csvname))
        df.insert(loc=1, column='date', value=[date]*len(df))
        df.to_csv(os.path.join(file_dir, csvname), index=False)
```

Sample input: `NYC_20180814_result.csv` in `some_path`:

```
   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
```

Same csv after executing `addDate(some_path)`:

```
   A      date  B  C
0  0  20180814  1  2
1  3  20180814  4  5
2  6  20180814  7  8
```

P.S. You'll not see the index column in your csv file.